# ImageButton dont fire after selecting a file from the file dialogbox (IE only)

Tags: asp.net, button, file-upload

this is my problem:

1. i have an image (browse.png) with a click event:

   ```
   <img src="Browse.png" runat ="server" id="image1"  onclick ="browse()" style="cursor:pointer" />
   ```

   function browse() {
       document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>').click();

   }
2. i have an invisible asp:fileupload.

   ```
       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
   ```
3. i have an ImageButton with serverside event:

   Protected Sub ImagebuttonSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
    End If

   End Sub
4. after you click the browse image the file dialogbox open, you select a file and then you press the ImagebuttonSend and nothing happen for the first click, the second clicks works but there his no file.
   this happen only in IE, works perfect in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing happens because there is an javascript error here

```
<img src="Browse.png" runat ="server" id="image1"  onclick ="browse()" style="cursor:pointer" />
function browse() {
    document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>').click();
// "ImagebuttonSend_Click"); // you should fix/remove that line!!
}
```

`"ImagebuttonSend_Click");` what is the purpose of that line and the syntax is wrong

Comment: first of all thanks but my question got wrong:  the javascript: function browse() {
    document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>').click();  
}